# MySQL request WHERE ... IN 

Tags: sql, mysql

in a table "partners", i've a field "sites" which can contain values like 1,27,38,12

then, in a website which has ID n°27, i would like to get partners associated to this website.

I tried this : 
`SELECT * FROM partners WHERE 27 IN (partners.sites)`

It works if 27 is at the beginning of the string (eg: 27,1,128) but it doesn't work if 27 is in the middle (eg: 1,27,38,12)

Have you got any idea to manage this ?

Thanks.
Cyril

Comment: You have a field that contains comma-separated values? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see the manual for find_in_set

Comment: Yeah, but it does exactly what Cyril asks for. It should be implemented as some kind of relation though, just as you pointed out. :)

Comment: @Alexander, I admit. It's a hideous solution to a hideous question.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make any sense

Why not make
`select * from partners where sites=27`?

Or are you suggesting that `sites` is a varchar containing CSV?
In this case this is totally wrong from any perspective. Do a one-to-many relationship in your database.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function, because the [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function will not expect a comma-separated string as an argument.

This does not work:

```
SELECT 27 IN ('1,27,5');
+------------------+
| 27 IN ('1,27,5') |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
```

This works:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(27, '1,27,5') > 0;
+-------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET(27, '1,27,5') > 0 |
+-------------------------------+
|                             1 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1, tentatively. Solves the problem at hand but enables continued use of a really bad database design. I think what really has to be done is getting to rid of the CSV field and use a 1:n relation table for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM partners WHERE partners.sites like '%27%'
```

Comment: If at all, then like this: `WHERE CONCAT(',',partners.sites,',') like '%,27,%'` - but that's hideous.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree that using relationships will not only be better practice, but will optimize your database request speeds as well, even if it's non noticeable, every bit counts.

So assuming you had a separate table called sites, you could do a call like follows:

SELECT * FROM partners WHERE pid IN (SELECT spid FROM sites WHERE siteid = 27);

Your relationship could then be something like:

```
-------------------------------------
PARTNERS
-------------------------------------
pid       | some field |
2         |            |
-------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
SITES
-------------------------------------
spid      | siteid     | surl
2         | 27         | http://...
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming sites is a field in the same table you're querying, you could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM partners WHERE sites LIKE %27;

SELECT * FROM partners WHERE sites LIKE 27;
```

Does that work?

Comment: not only does LIKE not help in this form, but also it expects 27 to be the only string there (which eliminates the need for LIKE) or at the end (why?)

Comment: True, it was a badly thought out solution to an already messy problem. I'd have to agree with creating a one to many many to one relationship instead.